# Aerospike over in-memory Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, in-memory-database, aerospike, database, nosql

I'm a bit of a noob with noSQL & cannot decide for Aerospike over complete in-memory Cassandra.

Use Case:
To be used for multiple services in our University ( From social platform to internal financial analytics to network logging to real-time messaging). Our daily active users are also constant(~5000). So my primary requirement is not to get 1M+ TPS but to reduce latency and maintain consistency serving the user data as fast as possible. The DB would be running on 3 bare metal servers with 32-vcore 128GB-Ram 256GB-SSD each connected in 10Gbit. The data won't be exceeding Ram as most of the data will be archived(to another ElacticSearch Server) every 6 Months.

Also, I don't mind to take the challenge and do a bit over-engineering & it's fine if the Cluster is hard to set-up but it should require little or no maintenance for years.

So looking over in-memory DB's Aerospike seemed a great choice. Then I was very exited to go blazingly fast but then I looked at [Aerospike total garbage?](https://medium.com/@drainingsun/aerospike-total-garbage-466663459562) &  [We use Aerospike heavily. It works just fine.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9496632) Now, this got me thinking it this the best fit for me?

Or should I go for complete in-memory Cassandra which is not optimised for complete in-memory table & still is less performant than Aerospike but has a better data model fit for me, does not have consistency issues and is tried & tested.( I am intrigued by ScyllaDB but it doesn't have in-memory tables)

I would like to have answers from people with production experience with Aerospike & Cassandra. Also please tell me if I am completely wrong.

Comment: The most reasonable way to answer this question is by running your own proof-of-concept on both systems and comparing them for your use case.

Comment: "Aerospike total garbage" use case discusses retrieving a large number of records using Secondary Index Query or Scan and with a node or multiple nodes going down during those operations. If your use case is about retrieving single user record (I gather thats what you are talking about) then you are not evaluating the critique to your use case.

Answer (score 4):

The Medium article is poorly written opinion from a faceless user, without data to back up the claims. Yes, Aerospike has [bugs](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html), as do all databases. GCE itself has [bugs](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559755) that can affect a distributed database such as Aerospike. I haven't seen any issue in the [aerospike/aerospike-server](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/issues) repo on GitHub talking about this user's problems on GCE. Usually people who use a software product in production will report a bug that affects them severely. The lack of a bug report is a "bad smell" - is it [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt)?

Aerospike is in fact used for high performance at high scale by many [customers](http://www.aerospike.com/customers/featured-customers/). I'm going to assume that even if said Medium blogger actually used Aerospike in production, it probably wasn't on the scale of 3Mtps reads and 1.5Mtps writes that AppNexus see for their Aerospike installation. Perhaps the proof of whether it's an appropriate Key-Value database for a production system is in its current use by real customers.

Let's address your specific question about whether to use Cassandra or Aerospike for a key-value use case. You probably want to start with high quality benchmarks comparing the two, but how do you determine if those are well done? Aerospike has published a [manifesto](http://www.aerospike.com/manifesto/) about what high quality benchmarking of databases should look like.

When you run into a benchmark, read all the way down the post and check the object sizes, the number of objects, size of the data set, length of the test. If the vendor [chose a tiny data set](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/redis-report-reviewed-the-little-nosql-benchmark-in-a-big-data-world/) and ran their test for a few minutes it isn't a valid benchmark. There's nothing to be learned from it about how the database would perform at real, sustainable loads, over realistic data sizes, for extended periods of time.

In the spirit of the manifesto, Aerospike has published a detailed benchmark versus both [Cassandra](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/comparing-nosql-databases-aerospike-and-cassandra/) and [ScyllaDB](http://www.aerospike.com/benchmarks/scylladb-initial/). Both show that Aerospike has consistently lower latencies with little variation, while the other databases have wild latency fluctuations. This is due to the architecture differences between the cache-first architecture of first generation NoSQL like Cassandra (also Couchebase, MongoDB, etc) and the [hybrid-memory architecture](http://www.aerospike.com/features/hybrid-memory-architecture/) design of Aerospike.

In a cache-first architecture, the database will first look to its in-memory caches for the keys and objects, and only go to disk when there's a cache-miss. The database then takes a big latency penalty for paging data from SSD into memory, and then operating on this memory. Such databases expect the [majority of reads to come out of cache](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/sizing-general.html). Once the cache hit ratio drops into a realistic range (not their hoped for 80% - 95%) a cache-first database will display latency spikes as it goes to disk. As a consequence, a Cassandra cluster needs lots of RAM across many nodes.

In the case of Aerospike, the hybrid-memory architecture (HMA) holds the [primary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/primary-index.html) (metadata about all the objects) in DRAM, and relies on [optimizations around SSD performance](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/storage.html) to fetch the data directly from disk at low latency. There's a wide range of performance between different SSDs (see [Aerospike on Intel Optane](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/intel-optanetm-ssds-aerospike-database-new-level-fast-operational-stores-hybrid-transactionalanalytical-processing/)), so you would use data from the open-source [ACT](https://github.com/aerospike/act) tool to understand what the sustainable read/write performance of the SSD is, while still achieving 95% of operations <= 1ms. HMA therefore requires very little memory per-node (64B per-object times the replication factor), resulting in smaller clusters. Data is served directly from SSD so you can expect consistently low latency for your operations, even at high scale.

If you're storing all your data fully in memory, take a look at [What's New in Aerospike 3.12?](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/) and [What's New in Aerospike 3.11?](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-in-aerospike-3-11/), as they include optimizations for such a use case. Specifically see [sprigs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#partition-tree-sprigs) and [CPU pinning](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#auto-pin).